# Div in out of container and in the left of full content

Tags: html, css

Can somebody help with any ideas, how to design one DIV in outside of Container? For better understanding, I post one image that shows my problem. Thanks from all!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRDSy.png)

Comment: position:absolute; left:0;

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi please show us code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Does that not achieve what you want?

Comment: <div class=”container”>
<div class=”row”>
<div class="all-operations">
<div class=”op1”></div>
<div class=”op1”></div>
<div class=”op1”></div>
<div class=”op1”></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

.all-operations {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #005f9b;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1300px;
    left: 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

If you use position `absolute` or `fixed` the inner div will be *outside* the container, however, you must make sure the parent **does not** have `position: relative` otherwise it will not work.

```css
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 70%;
  margin:0 auto;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.outside {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outside">im out</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using negative margins as well, if you want other content to flow as normal:

eg:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="outside">
      Example element to be outside container
   </div>
   <div class="another-content">
     Test content
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.outside {
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vvesmed2/